# Property 'setAppId' does not exist - Expo Onesignal

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, onesignal

I followed this [documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-expo-sdk-setup) to add Onesignal for notification to my expo app , on the app.tsx file i added the following code

```
import OneSignal from 'react-native-onesignal';


 useEffect(() => {
    
    OneSignal.setAppId("MyAppId");
  }, []);
```

i got the following Error

```
Property 'setAppId' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/Users/laptop/Documents/mobile_apps/appName/node_modules/react-native-onesignal/dist/index")'.ts(2339)
```

Comment: I am using the Onesignal Cordova plugin with Ionic/React and Capacitor, but I just had the same issue, so maybe my solution will help. 

Looking through the current code (5.0.0), I found the method, `initialize(<appId>)`. Implementing that particular method worked for me (` OneSignal.initialize("myAppId")`).

Note that it appears that many of the methods in the current documentation appear to no longer exist.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation suggestions you can either set the `oneSignalAppId` as an Extra param in the app.json / app.config.js (and then access it using Constants) or you can modify the code you have and instead use `initialize`. Which would look like:

```
OneSignal.initialize("YOUR_APP_KEY_HERE");
```

Note that you don't need to do this inside of a useEffect - it can just be at the file level.